# sending messages to all open sockets for a particular user

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm developing a personal web application where I would like to push messages specific to a user but in each tab they have open and with the possibility that the message may only go to one tab.

What I've done is give each socket object a unique identifier. I can send messages to that specific user but it only ever goes to the last tab opened. I can see that my socket does hold reference to both tabs. see below

```
{ id: '6121808001146368876',
  namespace: 
   { manager: 
      { server: [Object],
        namespaces: [Object],
        sockets: [Circular],
        _events: [Object],
        settings: [Object],
        handshaken: [Object],
        connected: [Object],
        open: [Object],
        closed: {},
        rooms: [Object],
        roomClients: [Object],
        oldListeners: [Object],
        flashPolicyServer: [Object],
        gc: [Object] },
     name: '',
     sockets: 
      { '8072595141256968141': [Object],
        '6121808001146368876': [Circular] },
     auth: false,
     flags: { endpoint: '', exceptions: [] },
     _events: { connection: [Function] } }
```

From what I see, I have reference under namespace.sockets but as I mentioned which ever is the Circular one is the only one that gets the message.

Can I get around that and if so how do I filter to a specific socket or does that need to be done by creating a namespace?

Also what is the significance of a socket that is just an object and one that's circular? From what I can see the main ID is the same as the one that's circular and the circular one is the last one connected.

Comment: `Circular` just means that it's self-referential, in some way. In your case, since the ids match, I'm guessing that `yourObj.namespace.sockets.6121808001146368876 === yourObj`. Regarding your problem, I suggest you leverage socket.io's channels, and let each user have their own channel. Then you don't have to manage the socket juggling yourself, but can instead `sockets.of(userChannel).emit(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution should be easy and there are several approachs.

The first one, and more complex is to store a pointer to all sockets for an user in a maintained structure, so for an specified user, you get an array or sockets or socket.id's and you have to add and remove the references manually... not recommended although factible (in fact, I do it this way in one of my projects).

The second one is easier letting Socket.IO managing all by himself. 
First you need unique id for each user (I would bet they have!) and when an user connects, you join him to a room with a name combination from the user ID:

```
socket.join( 'UserRoom' + userId );
```

On client disconnection, you remove him from his room:

```
socket.leave( 'UserRoom' + userId );
```

To broadcast a message to all opened user tabs from one specified user, just emit it with:

```
socket.broadcast.to( 'UserRoom' + userId ).emit( 'my fancy message' );
```

... or ...

```
io.sockets.in( 'UserRoom' + userId ).emit( 'my fancy message' );
```

Just need to add 1 line on connect/disconnect and library manages it all.